# No gradient of color with geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a raster image (ocean bathymetry) with geom_raster but I'm having a hard time to crack down the code. I would appreciate any help.

I've downloaded the following [xyz file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/umv70ze4hoym915/SF_bath.txt) (Dropbox link).

```
SF.bath <- read.table("SF_bath.txt", header=F,col.names=c("lon","lat","z"))
> head(SF.bath)
       lon     lat   z
1 -67.9917 50.9968 757
2 -67.9750 50.9968 693
3 -67.9583 50.9968 673
4 -67.9417 50.9968 769
5 -67.9250 50.9968 761
6 -67.9084 50.9968 733
```

When I try the following code, the colours do not show on my map?

```
v <- ggplot(SF.bath, aes(lon, lat,z=z))
print(v + geom_raster(aes(fill=z)) + stat_contour(size=0.2) + scale_fill_gradient("z"))
```

[image: map]

I get the following message: `Using alpha as value column: use value_var to override.` Any ideas of what might be the problem?

Comment: Using your example file, it works for me. What is your output of sessionInfo() and capabilities() as perhaps it's a package / dependency / version issue, or a device problem.  BTW, put the link to download the file in the q

Comment: FYI - Cross posted on the ggplot [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/K_jwTKUaxFg). (In the future, please don't cross-post.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDITED to emphasize the key answer**

The code in the question with the provided dataset achieves the desired result:

[image: plot of SF_bath]

After discussion in the comments, the key lesson turns out to be a suggestion that when the system behaves strangely, it may be wise to `update.packages()` as part of troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @gauden, I do have the latest version of ggplot2 and tried this example, but I get the same message : " Using alpha as value column: use value_var to override" and no colors on the map... any ideas?

Comment: @GodinA Do you want to upload your data to dropbox or other public site to see if the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Here's a dropbox link to access the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/umv70ze4hoym915/SF_bath.txt

Comment: I figure out the problem... turns out it was an easy one to fix! I was not using the most recent version of the reshape2 package (reshape2_1.2.1).
Now it works like a charm.Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. The easy ones are the hardest sometimes.